# Restore View to original xml state

Tags: android, view

In Android, is there an easy way to restore a view to the state as defined in the xml?

For example, I have this view in xml:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/set_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:ems="10"
    android:visibility="gone" >
</EditText>
```

Now programmatically, the visibility is set to visible, the user enters text into it, an error gets set with `.setError`, and now I want to simply revert the view to it's original state, without having to explicitly do:

```
 view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 view.setText("");
 view.setError(null);
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you will consider this to be an easy way but I tried the following.

Define the View you want to revert in its own xml ( I tried with a Button, playing with visibilty, text, ... )

button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/adminUser2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/admin_user" />
```

Then in your main layout define an insertion point

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonInsertLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
/>
```

In your activity load the View into the insertion point using the inflater

```
private Button admin;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    admin = (Button)View.inflate(UserLoggin.this, R.layout.button, null);
    ViewGroup insert = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.buttonInsertLayout);
    insert.addView(admin);
    // ...
}
```

Later on your reset() method you can inflate a new instance of the view, based on the xml content, and replace the modified one with the new one.

```
public void resetView() {
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)admin.getParent();
    int index = parent.indexOfChild(admin);
    parent.removeViewAt(index);
    // Inflate a fresh new View corresponding to the initial state of the view
    Button adminSave = (Button)View.inflate(UserLoggin.this, R.layout.button, null);
    parent.addView(adminSave, index);
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Yes.. not as easy as I would have liked, but it's very well possible that re-inflating the view is the only way to do this. For my current purpose, this would only make it more complicated, but I can imagine this could be a good approach if there are so many changes to the view that they can't be tracked.

Answer (score -1):

I unable to understand your question clearly. Anyway am answering, write the condition in Onresume() to revert your operation.

```
 Onresume(){
//write the condition
//do something for your view
super.onResume();
    }
```

Comment: My question is whether there exists a simple way to revert a View to its original XML state, something like `View.reset()`. I'm not asking how or where I can programmatically alter it.